# Does AWS manage move S3 objects to other tiers automatically after we create lifecycle management rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I have a bucket with objects in it, created a S3 lifecycle management rule and set it up so it moves all the objects into S3 IA after 30 days. Do I have to create a new bucket as the destination so after 30 days the objects go into that bucket or AWS manages that part automatically? Does AWS manage move S3 objects to other tiers automatically after we create lifecycle management rules or we should create those receiving buckets too?
Thank you

Comment: The objects don't move buckets due to lifecycle rules.  Their storage classes change (or they're removed if you setup expiration rules).

Comment: perfect, thank you. How can I test to see they are indeed being moved?

Comment: Nothing will move.  You can [check the storage class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/view-object-properties.html) in the web console or using [head-object](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/head-object.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, newly created S3 lifecycle rules do apply to both new and preexisting objects. Check [AWS documentation (2023 version)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-set-lifecycle-configuration-intro.html) for more tips related to lifecycle rules:

> When you add a Lifecycle configuration to a bucket, the configuration rules apply to both existing objects and objects that you add later. For example, if you add a Lifecycle configuration rule today with an expiration action that causes objects with a specific prefix to expire 30 days after creation, Amazon S3 will queue for removal any existing objects that are more than 30 days old.